# Unity - Resources folder, images and atlas

Tags: unity-game-engine, resources

I want to be able to load images on demand using Resources.Load function. But also to be efficient in regarding to draw calls, so I want to create an atlas for those images.

I was wondering what will happen if I'll place images under Resources folder and add a Sprite Atlas for them as well. Will the build package contain both the images and their atlas???

Is this the correct way to do that?

Comment: If you want to be efficient, drop the Resources folder and start using AssetBundles

Comment: I'm working in phases, for the first phase I wanted to use the Resources solution, and later on to use the AssetBundles

Answer (score 0):

There are no reason to include both if your looking for be efficient.
You make your atlas and all images are included here.

But answering to your question, yes you can have both images, and you can add 45 resource folders and copy again and again... but is not the correct way.

Is similar to compress a video to save space and you include in your storage device the compressed and uncompressed video.

Comment: But I want to load the spites from the Atlas on demand, how can I do that? Is there an option to get the all the Sprites under an Atlas? If there is then I can place only the Atlas under the Resources folder...

Comment: Well I can use SpriteAtlas as I understand

Comment: Yes you can use it on demand.
if you like to know how to use SpriteAtlas check the documentation and if have any question open a new question about it.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteAtlas.html